# Can I rewrite this sentence in this way?

Tags: word-order

> Wir haben nur eine kleine Wohnung, sind aber damit zufrieden.

Can I rewrite the above sentence in this way:

> Wir haben nur eine kleine Wohnung, aber wir sind damit zufrieden.

If yes, which sentence order would be the more commonly heard one?

Comment: I think the second version puts more emphasize on the "we". Some people might be not satisfied with our small apartment, but we are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ways are fine, and they are not preferred one way or another. (The current Google count is 10,100 vs. 10,200!)

Comment: How are you getting these counts? Google result counts can be misleading if not done carefully, and "false positives" are common.

Comment: In my opinion the repeated *wir* of the second example is more likely in conversation as opposed to writing.